# How can I OR together to gnumakefile conditions?

Tags: syntax, makefile, logic, boolean-expression, gnu-make

Using gmake v3.80, how can I create a rule that ORs together two things. I'm starting with this code:

```
ifeq "$(BUILD_ARCH)" "lnx86_22"
TEST_ARCH := i86
endif
ifeq "$(BUILD_ARCH)" "linux_24_i86"
TEST_ARCH := i86
endif
```

And would like to combine the two ifeq(s) into a single if that ORs the two conditions together, perhaps something like this?

```
ifeq "$(BUILD_ARCH)" "lnx86_22" OR "$(BUILD_ARCH)" "linux_24_i86"
TEST_ARCH := i86
endif
```

What is the actual syntax that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $(filter ...) for that.  Like this:

```
ifneq (,$(filter $(BUILD_ARCH),lnx86_22 linux_24_i86))
TEST_ARCH := i86
endif
```

Another option would be to use constructed variable names:

```
lnx86_22_ARCH :=     i86
linux_24_i86_ARCH := i86
    ...

TEST_ARCH := $($(BUILD_ARCH)_ARCH)

ifeq (,$(TEST_ARCH))
$(error Failed, unknown arch $(BUILD_ARCH))
Failed, unknown arch $(BUILD_ARCH)
endif
```

If you are able to upgrade to newer versions of GNU make there are other options available.

Comment: Please give the ways of doing this in v3.82.